# mysql query for extracting names separated by ";" and check if it is selected in combobox

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6

I have a combobox which consists of StoreNames: X,Y,Z
If any storename is selected say for eg. X then i need to get all names whose StoreName is: X
The table containing names and storename has the below structure:

```
Name      StoreName  
A         X,Y  
B         Y,Z  
C         X,Z  
D         X 
E         Z
```

and so on...

How to extract "X" from StoreName and get Names : A,C,D through mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM yourtable
WHERE storename LIKE '%yourchoice%'
```